Ultrafilters in posets
I have read about filters in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter), and I've seen that sets of form $F_p = \{x : p \leq x\}$ are ultrafilters. How can I prove it using definition of ultrafilter? (filter that is not a subfilter for any other filter).

MSE is not a "do my homework/work for me" site. Posts like this (e.g. "PSQs") are in poor taste, & often downvoted & closed; we expect users to put in effort! If you want meaningful help, [edit] your post to add relevant context (more), e.g. relevant definitions, your work/attempts, the problem's source, where specifically you're stuck, what you do/don't understand & have learned recently, & so on. If needed: this is useful for formatting LaTeX, & Approach0 helps find past questions.
